# Safari failing to follow server-side redirect with https and hash params

Tags: redirect, web, https, safari

Safari (8.0.7 in my case) is failing to follow a redirect.  This is working in Chrome and only fails in a very specific scenario.

As best I can tell, the redirect will only fail when moving between two https connections on different domains/subdomains when hash params are involved.  It will work with query params or if one of the domains is localhost.

According to https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24175, it seems that Safari would not honor hash params in redirects at one point in the past, but I cannot confirm if this is still the case.

It's looking to be a security/sandbox issue, but I'd be interested if anyone can put an exact finger on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, this did prove to be a big of a Safari issue, but also a perfect storm of things which resulted in my problem.

**tl;dr:**

Safari doesn't apply hash params on redirects unless the paths match exactly.  Fixed in Safari 9.x

**Specifics:**

The server infrastructure was redirecting `/foo` to `/foo/`.  Because of this, the original hash params were not re-applied.

`http://localhost:<port>/foo#/one`

results in

`http://localhost:<port>/foo`

Forcing the trailing slash fixed the issue

`http://localhost:<port>/foo/#/one`

results in

`http://localhost:<port>/foo/#/one`